# Keyword is not an expression error

Tags: python, python-3.5

I keep getting an error that says this keyword can't be an expression and I don't know why.  It runs when I remove one of the variables but when I try to run all 3 it comes up with this error.

```
Size = 10
NUMBER = 10
#  Define main process
def main():
    address_book()

def address_book():
    names = [''] * SIZE
    phone_numbers = [''] * SIZE
    e_mails = [''] * SIZE

    for counter in range(0, SIZE):
        print('Please enter the name #', end='')
        names[counter] = input(str(counter + 1) + ': ')

        print('Please enter the phone #', end='')
        phone_numbers[counter] = input(str(counter + 1) + ': ')

        print('Please enter e-mail address#' + end='')
        e_mails[counter] = input(str(counter + 1) + ': ')

        print()


main()
```

Comment: typo? Why is there a plus not a comma here? `'Please enter e-mail address#' + end=''`

Comment: with my professor we've been doing it this way so that the lines don't get too long.  when you are suing strings you can replace the commas with a + and it'll still work

Comment: No, that doesn't work this time.

Comment: ok I'll try changing it

Comment: so I tried putting them in a straight line to see if it would work but I'm getting similar errors now

Comment: sorry forgot the code

Comment: names[counter] = input('Please enter the name #', (counter + 1), ': ')
phone_numbers[counter] = input('Please enter the name #', (counter + 1), ': ')
e_mails[counter] = input('Please enter the name #', (counter + 1), ': ')

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python/CIS1400labs/Assingments/Homework_08.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:/Python/CIS1400labs/Assingments/Homework_08.py", line 16, in main
    address_book()
  File "G:/Python/CIS1400labs/Assingments/Homework_08.py", line 26, in address_book
    names[counter] = input('Please enter the name #', (counter + 1), ': ')
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: there are the error messages I'm getting

Comment: ok I got it to work... It was a typo on my third input statement.  I didn't define it as a string and I separated the sentence and the end='' with a + sign when it should have been a comma.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have noticed that you can combine separate string arguments to the `print` function with either the comma or the plus sign. That is fine when those string arguments are nameless ones.

```
print('Please enter ', 'e-mail address#') # ok
print('Please enter ' + 'e-mail address#') # ok
```

However, you cannot use that same change in syntax from the comma to the plus when the parameter on one side of the comma is the *named* parameter `end=''`.

```
print('Please enter e-mail address#', end='') # ok
print('Please enter e-mail address#' + end='') # not ok
```

When you use the plus sign on strings, it tells Python to concatenate the strings. That means sticking the strings together to make a single string. It doesn't make sense to do that with a named argument like `end=''`. Consequently Python doesn't even allow writing the plus between a named argument and any other argument.